# !important is part of CSS3 or CSS 2

Tags: css

I am wondering !important rules is came from CSS1, 2 or 3 ? Can any one let me know please.
Example :

```
.btn{
color:#fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was introduced in the spec for css1. You can find the full spec [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/) and there are several mentions of `!important` in there, specifically point 3.2

> 3.2    Cascading order

Conflicting rules are intrinsic to the CSS mechanism. To find the value for an element/property combination, the following algorithm must be followed:

- Sort the declarations by explicit weight: declarations marked
  '!important' carry more weight than unmarked (normal) declarations.

Here's some further reading [when you should/shouldn't use](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) !important in your css, and here's a [post on the introduction of !important](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/) that's well worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

It's from CSS1. Here you can read it's documentation.

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1-961217